# Internet connection issue after sleep

Tags: suspend, internet

When I leave my computer alone and it enters sleep mode, after I return it cannot connect to the WiFi unlike before. I don't alter anything, I just leave it be but upon returning it simply cannot connect to any WiFi connection.

[EDIT]
My device is a [Dell Inspiron 3543](https://www.wootware.co.za/dell-3543-inspiron-intel-core-i7-5500u-2-4-ghz-processor-8gb-single-channel-ddr3l1tb-5400rpm-hdd-nvidia-geforce-840m-15-6-1366-x-768-led-windows-8-1-pro-64-bit-multi-language-notebook.html)

I don't have any power saving settings on.

Upon executing `lspci` I get this:

```
06:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 07)
```

Upon executing `lshw -class network` I get:

```
*-network                 
   description: Wireless interface
   product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
   vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
   logical name: wlp6s0
   version: 01
   serial: 2c:33:7a:fa:4c:ed
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.271 (r587334) ip=192.168.1.111 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:18 memory:ab200000-ab207fff
*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
   logical name: enp7s0
   version: 07
   serial: 74:e6:e2:45:a5:64
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 100Mbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:19 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:ab100000-ab100fff memory:d2100000-d2103fff
```

Upon executing `ip link show` I get:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp7s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether 74:e6:e2:45:a5:64 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp6s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
link/ether 2c:33:7a:fa:4c:ed brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

[/EDIT]

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and it's on a Dual Boot with Windows 10, if that changes anything.

What can I do to fix this issue?
Thanks

Comment: It depends on the hardware - please [edit] and post it - and the energy saving settings, probably.

Comment: Done! Hope this helps.

Comment: We need the exact WiFi device and the same model can be shipped with many different ones. Please either do `lspci` in Ubuntu and copy/paste the relevant line or check the Device Manager in Windows.

Comment: Will this suffice?

Comment: Yes, thanks. Check this https://askubuntu.com/q/55868/880592 and make sure you have the correct/recommended driver installed.

Comment: I will check if this solution works for me, thank you very much!